# What is correct way to use NVM?

Tags: windows, node.js, nvm

Problem while switching the Node Versions in windows.

I have installed NVM to my Windows system to manage node versions, i have also installed NodeJS earlier version using NVM. You can check with the image attached for the better clarifications.

Please find the link for the image as stackoverflow is not permitting me to post images for less than 10 repo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np9TP.png

From the image you can make out, NVM list is displayed with the multiple versions of Node but its asking me to install again and agaian when i switch to it and use.

Can anybody assist me with this. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing an issue with the architecture. Try typing `nvm arch 32` to set the system default to 32-bit, then `nvm install 0.10.32`, and finally `nvm use 0.10.32`. The fact that the tool is showing `?-bit architecture` means it is having trouble deciphering which system architecture you're using.

As the author of NVM for Windows, I'd really like to know which version of Windows you're running this on and whether you're running a 32 or 64 bit Windows installation. If there is a bug or something I can do to make this problem not happen again, I'll do it.

Comment: Try upgrading to version 1.1.0.